# Best way to leave a job after ~2 months

Tags: new-job, resignation

I started a front-end developer position with a company (Company A) about two weeks ago. Briefly, it's fine, I don't love it, and was never planning on staying for more than a year or two.

Out of the blue, a company (Company B) that I applied for a position with months before I accepted the position with Company A reached out to do an interview and some technical assessments. During the interview, we discussed why there was a 4 month gap between applying and getting an interview, everything seems fine, and long story short, they offered me a position with literally double the salary I'm being paid at Company A. On top of that, the work at Company B is so much more in alignment with my interests and long-term goals, so there really isn't much decision to consider here; I'm absolutely accepting the offer.

My question is: what is the most gracious way to resign from Company A? I'd almost never apply for a role immediately after accepting one, and even though I applied to Company B first, I know the optics aren't good for me. Should I bother putting in a two weeks notice? I'm on a team with a few other developers at Company A and work at the moment is so slow that I've gone through some days without looking at a single line of code. I'm obviously not concerned with listing the short time on my resume or asking for a reference, but I'm just wondering how to make my way out the door while saving as much face as possible.

Comment: How do Company A and Company B relate to [Company X and Company Y in your previous question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/180335/a-past-long-term-client-reached-out-from-out-of-the-blue-with-a-full-time-salar)?

Comment: There is absolutely no gracious way to resign from company A. Make sure you have a signed contract from Company B. Clean out your desk of all the mementos you want to keep in advance, and just resign. Offer your two weeks. And don't be surprised if they tell you to get out immediately. And whatever you do, don't tell anyone which company you're going to, even your friends. And don't update your linkedIn for 8 months at least. HR may find out when the reference check is done, but HR is less likely to try to sabotage your new position than your current manager/director.

Comment: You just hop on the bus, Gus, making new plans, Sam...

Comment: If you're still in your probation period then personally I don't see issues. I've seen companies cut people off without a backward glance because they didn't fit during that. I would just submit a written resignation with a finishing date based on your contractual obligation.

Comment: How is this question different to any of the other dozens of "how do I resign" questions on this site?

Answer (score 5):

> My question is: what is the most gracious way to resign from Company
> A?

Tell them immediately.

They won't be happy, but perhaps their second choice is still available.

> Should I bother putting in a two weeks notice?

If your current employer wants you to work a two week notice period, it would be gracious to agree to do so.

Comment: important to add: make sure you've actually signed the new contract before doing anything

Answer (score 5):

1. Read you contract, employee handbook and and brush up on local labor policies. These vary wildly across the world, location and company
2. Specifically check for any "probation" terms. In probation a separation is typically quick and painless. It's specifically designed to give an easy exit if things don't work out for either party.
3. Make sure you understand and follow all steps that you agreed to in writing. That may include notice periods, back pay of signing bonus, relo or other hiring benefits, shipping of corp property etc.
4. Give notice in accordance with the legal requirements and your desired time line.
5. Be sure to thank for the opportunity they gave to you and be polite and then you just have to see how they take it.

They may be miffed, they may be not. There is nothing you can do other than playing it "clean".